# Incorrect result in JavaScript calculation

Tags: javascript, calc

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and wanted to convert one of my calculation spreadsheets to something I can use on a web page. However, the calculation gives me an incorrect result.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function calc() {
            var onerepmax = document.wodCalculate.oneRepMax.value;
            var percent = document.wodCalculate.percentOfOneRepMax.value / 100;
            var addkg = document.wodCalculate.plusKg.value;
            var zwischenschritt = onerepmax * percent;
            var gewicht = zwischenschritt + addkg;
            document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML = gewicht;
        };
</script>
```

and here's the HTML:

```
<form action="" id="wodCalculate" name="wodCalculate">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
            <tr><td>1 Rep Max</td><td><input type=text name="oneRepMax" value="">&nbsp;kg<br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>% vom 1RM</td><td><input type=text name="percentOfOneRepMax" value="">&nbsp;%<br></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Plus x kg</td><td><input type=text name="plusKg" value="">&nbsp;kg<br></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calc()"></td></tr>
        </table>
</form>
<div id="weight">Weight</div>
```

It works fine up to the point of multiplying the "onerepmax" with the "percent". However, once it gets to the point of adding the "addkg" to the result of the multiplication (i.e. giving me the "gewicht"), the result becomes incorrect.

For example, I want to get 10% of 100kg and add 10kg. Instead of 20kg, the calculation result is 1010.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [Number() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `value` of an `input` is always a string, so `+` ends up being string concatenation (`"10" + "10"` is `"1010"`, as opposed to `10 + 10` which is `20`).

**If** you're using an `input type="number"` (the OP isn't, but others finding this answer may) and the browser supports them, you can use [`valueAsNumber`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-input-valueasnumber) instead:

```
var onerepmax = document.wodCalculate.oneRepMax.valueAsNumber;
```

If you're using `type="text"` or the browser doesn't support `valueAsNumber`:

You can convert user-input values using `parseInt(value, 10)` (the 10 = decimal, base 10) if they're meant to be whole numbers, e.g.:

```
var onerepmax = parseInt(document.wodCalculate.oneRepMax.value, 10);
```

That's just one option, though, you have several:

- The unary `+` operator:  `value = +value` will coerce the string to a number using the JavaScript engine's standard rules for that. The number can have a fractional portion (e.g., `+"1.50"` is `1.5`). Any non-digits in the string (other than the `e` for scientific notation) make the result `NaN`. Also, `+""` is `0`, which may not be intuitive.

  ```
  var onerepmax = +document.wodCalculate.oneRepMax.value;
  ```
- The `Number` function: `value = Number(value)`. Does the same thing as `+`.

  ```
  var onerepmax = Number(document.wodCalculate.oneRepMax.value);
  ```
- The `parseInt` function, usually with a radix (number base): `value = parseInt(value, 10)`. The downside here is that `parseInt` converts any number it finds at the beginning of the string but **ignores** non-digits later in the string, so `parseInt("100asdf", 10)` is `100`, not `NaN`. As the name implies, `parseInt` parses only a whole number.

  ```
  // (Same as the first one above)
  var onerepmax = parseInt(document.wodCalculate.oneRepMax.value, 10);
  ```
- The `parseFloat` function: `value = parseFloat(value)`. Allows fractional values, and always works in decimal (never octal or hex). Does the same thing `parseInt` does with garbage at the end of the string, `parseFloat("123.34alksdjf")` is `123.34`.

  ```
  var onerepmax = parseFloat(document.wodCalculate.oneRepMax.value);
  ```

So, pick your tool to suit your use case. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're "adding" a string, not a number. The `+` operator in JavaScript has multiple semantics, and as soon as one operand is a string, it will do string concatenation.

To prevent that, convert the string to a number with the unary `+` operator.