# Axios is parsing typescript object not correctly

Tags: json, typescript, axios

I've got a typescript object of my user, which includes an `id: number`. This id is getting parsed from axios internally as string, which is wrong and not accepted by my server, so I want to fix this.

My axios call looks like this :
`axios.post(`${url}`, user, { withCredentials: true });` and the User object looks like this :

```
export default class User {
    Id: number;

    Username: string;

    Password: string;

    constructor(Id: number, Username: string, Password: string) {
      this.Id = Id;
      this.Username = Username;
      this.Password = Password;
    }
}
```

The parsed object looks like this :        `"{"Id":"1337","Username":"test","Password":"admin"}"`

The expected object would look like this : `"{"Id":1337,"Username":"test","Password":"admin"}"`

My idea was to manually build the json and stringify it, but since axios is internally using stringify again, this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: `axios` is almost certainly not responsible for this. Where/how do you populate the `Id` property on the object?

Comment: Thank you, I'm a native developer and didn't expect, that typescript would allow me to put a string into a number property... I assigned the value of a select html element directly to my id, which in fact was a string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agree with you. there is something wrong here.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't exist at runtime, only at *transpilation* time - if what comes over the wire is `"{\"Id\": \"1337\"}"` then the value of the `Id` attribute will be a string.

Comment: Duplicate of [Incorrect result in JavaScript calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945779/incorrect-result-in-javascript-calculation/32945816#32945816) (`value` is always a string).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrect result in JavaScript calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945779/incorrect-result-in-javascript-calculation)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to axios. I've taken the value from an `<select>` tag and put it directly into my Id property. This value was a string and so was my id property a string which caused the problem. Casting the value on initialization as number worked: `Number(this.updatedUserId)` and solved my problem.

This also gets further explained here : [Incorrect result in JavaScript calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945779/incorrect-result-in-javascript-calculation/32945816#32945816)